# Area of a square inscribed in a triangle?

Tags: geometry

Construct a triangle ABC whose base AB is 24 and altitude CH is 16.

Hence, inscribe a square EPGF (one of whose sides lies along AB) and calculate its area.

My book suggests to use triangle similarity. Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 3 approaches here, I think Saptrashi's answer would be best for you, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532122/maximum-area-of-a-square-in-a-triangle/708192#708192

Answer (score 1):

$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle FGC$, hence $$\frac{AB}{CH} = \frac{FG}{CH-PG}$$