# Prove $a+b \leq 1$ with two disjoint squares in a larger square.

Tags: geometry, inequality

> Two disjoint squares are located inside a square of side $1$. If the lengths of the sides of the two squares are $a$ and $b$, prove $a+b \leq 1$.

I thought about setting up a coordinate axes with the leftmost vertex of the square at the origin. Then I will have to show that the sum of the side lengths is less than or equal to $1$ while the two squares being disjoint and still inside the square. This is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ NOTE: this is a heavy edit of the original answer, which fixes a wrong assumption and adds some more detail. ]

Here is the outline of a proof. The squares will be considered "open sets" i.e. not including their actual borders, which allows for a vertex of one square to lie on the side of the other, or two sides from different squares to overlap - and still be disjoint. (With the alternative interpretation of squares as "closed sets" the inequality would become a strict one $a + b \lt 1$.)

The proof relies on the following two propositions.

**(1)** A line can be drawn which separates the squares into different half-planes.

This follows from the general statement about separability of convex bodies in an n-dimensional Euclidian space known as the [Hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem):

> if both disjoint convex sets are open, then there is a hyperplane in between them

In the 2-dimensional case, the *hyperplane* is simply a straight line, and one such possible line is actually the separating bitangent (common tangent) of the two convex areas.

**(2)** Let $\Delta ABC$ be a right triangle with the right angle at $A$. The largest square "inscribed" in $\Delta ABC$ has a vertex at $A$, two sides along the legs $AB, AC$, and $AA'$ as a diagonal, where $A' \in BC$ is the foot of the bisector through $A$.

For an arbitrary triangle (not necessarily a *right* one), it can be shown that the largest inscribed square has two vertices on one side of the triangle, and (at least) one other vertex on another side. It can also be shown that the side of the square is $\frac{a h}{a + h}$ where $a$ is the length of the side where the square "sits" and $h$ is the length of the corresponding altitude. This is proved for example at [Maximum area of a square in a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532122/maximum-area-of-a-square-in-a-triangle).

In the case of a right triangle, there are just two candidate such squares, one "sitting" on both legs, the other one on the hypothenuse.

[image: in_square_1]

Let $a, b, c$ be the lengths of the sides, and $h$ the length of the altitude through $A$. Then the general formula gives the sides of the squares as $\frac{b c}{b + c}$ and  $\frac{a h}{a + h}$ respectively. To conclude the proof, it remains to be shown that:

$$
\frac{b c}{b + c} \ge \frac{a h}{a + h}
$$

Noting that $b c = a h = 2 S$ where $S$ is the area of the triangle, and $h = \frac{b c}{a}$, the inequality reduces to:

$$
a + \frac{b c}{a} \ge b + c \\
a^2 - a (b + c) + b c \ge 0 \\
(a - b) (a - c) \ge 0
$$

Since $a \ge b, c$ the last inequality holds, and proposition (2) is thus proved.

Now, back to the question in point here. By proposition **(1)** there is a line separating the two inner squares, for example:

[image: in_squares_2]

If the separating line is parallel to one of the sides of the outer square, then each inner square can be inscribed in a larger one with sides parallel to the outer square edges, and the two newly constructed squares have sides which obviously add up to $\le 1$ so it follows that $a + b \le 1$.

[image: in_squares_3]

If the separating line is not parallel to any of the outer square sides, then it will intersect all of them - two internally (within the side segments of the outer square) and two externally. This forms two right angle triangles sharing part of the hypothenuse, each of them containing one of the inner squares. From proposition **(2)** each of the inner squares must be smaller than the respective one drawn in red, whose sides obviously add up to $1$, so it again follows that $a + b \le 1$, which concludes the proof.

[image: in_squares_4]

(This last drawing shows the case when the separating line intersects two *opposite* edges of the outer square. The layout is slightly different in the other case, when it intersects two *adjacent* edges, but the same construction and same argument apply in that case as well.)

P.S. I am a bit curious about the background/context of this question, since it doesn't look like a run-of-the-mill exercise.

Comment: The separating line doesn't necessarily need to pass through both vertices, right?

Comment: @user19405892 Right. The line in the drawings is actually a separating bitangent, which is a particular case of a separating line (for _open_ convex sets, strictly speaking).

Comment: I don't see why we need $2$ cases then. We can always just use the line separating the two that isn't tangent and apply the result--which you mentioned earlier but deleted--that the diagonal of a square inscribed in a right triangle is less than or equal to the length of the internal bisector of the right angle.

Comment: @user19405892 Think of two inner squares with sides parallel to the outer one, stacked on top of each other. There is only one separating line, and that line is parallel to a side of the outer square, so it doesn't form the two triangles where proposition (2) applies. So that is a case that must be considered separately.

Comment: In that case they wouldn't be disjoint so you can't do that.

Comment: @user19405892 It depends on whether you consider them as open vs. closed sets. As I wrote at the top of my proof, I considered them _open_ `"The squares will be considered "open sets" i.e. not including their actual borders, which allows for a vertex of one square to lie on the side of the other, or two sides from different squares to overlap - and still be disjoint"`. I assumed that's what you had in mind since you wrote the inequality as _not_ strict $a+b \le 1$. If you prefer to think of them as closed sets, then you can actually stregthen the conclusion to a strict inequality $a+b \lt 1$.

Comment: I don't see how you can get $a+b < 1$.

Comment: @user19405892 Use the version for closed (and compact) sets of the separation theorem. From the link I posted: `In the first version of the theorem, if both these sets are closed and at least one of them is compact, then there is a hyperplane in between them and even two parallel hyperplanes in between them separated by a gap`. Note the `two parallel hyperplanes ... separated by a gap` part. That non-0 gap is enough to ensure a strict $a+b \lt 1$ inequality.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Unfortunately, my tips only work if you assume the inner squares' sides are parallel to the outer squares' sides. I will try to find some way to prove this if you do not assume that.

Let's say that the square of area $1$ is from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$. Then, let's say the square of side length $a$ is from $(l_a, h_a)$ to $(l_a+a, h_a+a)$. Also, similarly, let's say the square of side length $b$ is from $(l_b, h_b)$ to $(l_b+b, h_b+b)$. A point $(x_0, y_0)$ is within the square of side length $a$ if and only if $l<=x_0<=l+a$ and $h<=y_0<=h+a$. Since the square of side length $b$ is disjoint with this square, this means that $l_b > l_a+a$ or $l_b+b < l_a$ or $h_b > h_a+a$ or $h_b+b < h_a$.

Also, since all of these points must be inside the original square, we know that all of these coordinates must be in $[0, 1]$. Since the maximum difference of two numbers in $[0, 1]$ is $1-0=1$, we know that the difference of any two coordinates must also be less than or equal to $1$.

You now have four cases for which to prove your theorem. For each case, try subtracting the maximum x- or y-coordinate from the minimum x- or y-coordinate of both squares and then showing that for this difference to be less than or equal to $1$, $a+b \leq 1$. For example, for the first case, the maximum x-coordinate is $l_b+b$ and the maximum y-coordinate is $l_a$, so try using $(l_b+b)-l_a \leq 1$ to prove the theorem. Use the inequality from the first case ($l_b > l_a+a$) to get rid of $l_b$ from the inequality so that the $l_a$s will cancel out. Do something similar for each case.

I hope these suggestions help!

Comment: This seems to be focused on the cases when the interior squares have sides parallel to the coordinate axes. Not sure if we can ignore the other cases or how difficult they are to deal with, but it seems worth mentioning.

Comment: @pjs36 Thank you for noticing that! I know that the proof above is valid, but you are right that I made that assumption and that assumption was not stated in the problem.

Comment: I only caught it because I'd been thinking about the problem, and that was the tricky one -- it's even *more* intuitive that slanted squares need to be smaller, but hard to frame an argument around, I felt.