# Square inscribed inside triangle, solve for area around square

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

A square is inscribed into and isosceles triangle with base length 10 and legs 13.

I don't know where to start. Maybe use Pythagorean theorem to find height? And then what?

Comment: Consider the similar triangle which lies on top of the square (i.e. the base is the top of the square). It has the same angles as the original triangle (which can be determined using the side lengths given), so you can find the base, which corresponds to the length of the square.

Comment: @Dave How do I find the angles based on side lengths?

Comment: Well, a way that always works is the cosine law. If the sides of a triangle (of any type) are $a,b,c$, then $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos (A)$ where $A$ is the angle opposite of side $a$. This can be repeated for the other angles, and since you know the side lengths you can rearrange to solve for $A$ as such: $$\cos (A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$

Comment: There are $3$ squares inscribed in a triangle (two of them equal for an isosceles triangle) so you'll have to decide which one to work on. See [Maximum area of a square in a triangle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532122/maximum-area-of-a-square-in-a-triangle) for some possible ideas.

Comment: Can anyone post a straightforward solution? Haven't learned Trig yet.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/708192/291201) answer to the linked question uses no trigonometry. The two different squares that can be inscribed in your triangle have sides of $60/11$ and $1560/289$, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider a square with a side upon the base ($10$) of the triangle, you can call the side of the square as $2x$; the height of the triangle is $12$ as you can check by Pythagorean theorem. You can draw the height so that the isosceles triangle is divided into equal parts. Now if you consider similar right triangles, one on the top of the square (it will have base $x$ and height $12-2x$) and the other one on the right side of the square (it will have base $5-x$ and height $2x$), you can write the following proportion between the heights and the bases of the two triangle:

\begin{equation}
2x:(12-2x)=(5-x):x\\(2x)(x)=(12-2x)(5-x)\\ 2x^2=60-12x-10x+2x^2\\11(2x)=60\\2x=\frac{60}{11}
\end{equation}

The area of the isosceles triangle is $\frac{10*12}{2}=60$, for the square we have $\left(\frac{60}{11}\right)^2$...now it is easy.

Comment: How is it $2x^2$, shouldnt it be $4x^2$

Comment: @GerardL. No because it comes from $2x*x$ in the proportion..

Comment: In the answer can you explain how you got 12-2x and 5-x, as well as the other expressions? Makes it a lot more clear.